# session cookie not being sent back to server on a per-request basis

Tags: python, cookies

I'm trying to implement an authentication system, part of which involves passing around a session cookie to allow the server to verify the user's identity on a per-request basis; however, when registering under a test-case and attempting to access an authenticated endpoint, despite the cookie being set in the test's local cookiejar, it does not appear in the request headers to the server.

The server creates the cookie here, by only setting the expiration date.

```
headers={
    "set-cookie": [{
        "name": "__session",
        "value": user_obj.serialize_session(),
        "expires": cookie_expiry(user_obj.expires_at()),
    }]
}
```

And the test-case is very simple

```
session = requests.Session()

def register(username, password):
    return session.post(
        f"{HOST}/api/auth/register",
        ...
    )

def create_invoice(education, desc, budget, deadline, files):
    return session.post(
        f"{HOST}/api/invoice/create",
        ...
    )


username, password = ...
account = register(username, password)
req = create_invoice(
    ...
)
# {"status": "error", "reason": "you must be authenticated to use this endpoint"}
```

On the client-side, the cookie appears to be valid on the `register` response:

> 'set-cookie': '__session="..."; expires=Fri, 22-Apr-2022 02:47:46 GMT'

But, the request from the server-side appears without any `Cookie` header:

```
Host: www.example.local:8443
User-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 112
Content-Type: application/json
```

I've looked everywhere in terms of playing around with the `Domain` and `HttpOnly` attributes, but nothing appears to work. Is there a certain reason why the `request`s session isn't putting the session cookie in the request?

Comment: does it work in a browser?

Comment: @Marat identical behaviour in a browser using jQuery's `$.post`

Comment: then it looks like the problem is on the server side

Comment: testing it further, it appears like the browser is selectively recalling the cookie only when calling the `register` endpoint, but i cannot find it anywhere in local/session storage. this is strange

Comment: cookies are shared storage, sent back and forth in its entirety with every request. If server doesn't send cookies back, they're considered deleted by the browser. Just by the description it looks to be the case